# Using blade data value into another one within layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to use a variable value into another one (*both are in the same table as keys*) and display in a blade layout the **container variable value**. Both variables are passed using the `with` method from the controller. Is that possible? 
Here a quick demo of what I'm loooking for :

```
# controller method 
public function build()
{
    return $this
    ->view('emails.registration_following')
    ->with( ['name' => 'Nick', 'text' => 'Hello {{ $name }}'] ) # Here goes the thing
    ;
}
```

And the `blade.php` looks like :

```
<html>
    <body>
      <p> {{ $text }} </p>    
    </body>
</html>
```

The expect output by me is `Hello Nick`but I got `Hello {{Nick}}`. I know that brackets here, are treated like `String` but how to circumvine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I did not need to pass two variables but just one and put in its value all needed other variables to form my expected text. 
It was a bad idea to do what I was asking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining the variable in the function first:

```
# controller method 
public function build()
{
    $name = 'Nick';

    return $this
      ->view('emails.registration_following')
      ->with( ['name' => $name, 'text' => "Hello $name"] ) # Here goes the thing
    ;
}
```

In this way, you have both `$name` and `$text` accessible in the view.

Comment: It's quite a good idea. Looking at your code made me figure out that I did not need to pass two variables but just one and put in its value all needed other variables.

Comment: Thanks. How did I not see it?

Comment: Thanks, @CfassKing. This is what StackOverflow is for. If possible please upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried like this below?

```
public function build()
{
    $name = 'Nick';
    return $this
    ->view('emails.registration_following')
    ->with( ['name' => $name , 'text' => 'Hello '.$name] ) # Here goes the thing
    ;
}
```

Comment: It's quite a good idea. Looking at your code made me figure out that I did not need to pass two variables but just one and put in its value all needed other variables.
Thanks. How did I not see it?

Answer (score 0):

`with( ['name' => 'Nick', 'text' => "Hello $name"] )` Please use double quote